# slideup Jquery function cant seem to get it work?

Tags: jquery

Slideup jquery doesnt work.

```
$(".close_basket").click(function() {
        $(".mybasket").slideUp(1000);
    });
```

HTML :

```
<div class="mybasket">more code...

<div class="close_basket">
<span>Close <img src="images/close.png"  alt="*" /></span>
</div></div>
```

So I want to click on close basket and it should slide up and content mybasket disapear.

Comment: is the script in dom ready handler

Comment: Seems fine to me. http://jsfiddle.net/5579R/

Comment: any error in the browser console?

Comment: Probably something in your css. Can you post the relevant css?

Comment: You must wrap the script in document ready function to make this to work

Comment: Try wrapping your code in `jQuery(function($){
    $(".close_basket").click(function () {
        $(".mybasket").slideUp(1000);
    });
})`

Comment: tnx for wrapping advice it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vkasarora/DmgGQ/3/).. Check out the jsfiddle I have created.
Secondly, see if you have included the jquery file in your code.

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
```

Thirdly, Check your css.